# Creating gap between adjacent div in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created three divs and I am trying to create slight gap between the divs.

This is how it is right now.

[image]
I want to create gap here.

[image]
Here is the HTML and CSS (the div runs thrice in a loop)

```
<div class="album-border col-lg-4" style="margin: 1px 0px;">
    <p>Div</p>
</div>

.album-border {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one way you could do it. You can assign a width to `.album-border` so that it can have some space. After that you can wrap them in a `div` with css properties `justify-content: space-between;` and `display: flex;` Hope this helps

```css
.album-border {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 31%;
}

.div-wrapper {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrapper">
  <div class="album-border col-lg-4" style="margin: 1px 0px;">
    <p>Div</p>
  </div>
  <div class="album-border col-lg-4" style="margin: 1px 0px;">
    <p>Div</p>
  </div>
  <div class="album-border col-lg-4" style="margin: 1px 0px;">
    <p>Div</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.album-border:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 5px
}
```

This should do it.